# PhoneStateListener and LocationManager inside a Timer, how to? (Android)

Tags: android, timer, background, locationmanager, phone-state-listener

I am developing an app that the main objective is collect data from the sensors in the background and send it to a DataBase. To do so, I am using a `Remote Service` for taking the data from the background.

Inside the `Service`, I have a periodic `TimerTask` in a `Timer`, that does:

1. Check sensors setting
2. Activate sensors which data is wanted
3. Take the data
4. Stop sensors

I decide to start and stop the sensors every time because it is done every 30 sec, and it's better than have them set. Moreover, I have the same problem if I set them before and add a new one that wasn't set, and setting all them is not efficient as the GPS drains a lot the battery.

The problem is that `PhoneStateListener` and `LocationManager` don't work inside a non looper thread (`Timer` is a non looper thread).

Is there any way to solve this problem? Is there any trick to skip it?

Comment: you better start service for GPS data collection and when it's achieved stop the service inside there!

Comment: @Saqib I tried to start a Remote Service inside the TimerTask, but I get the same problem.

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: what do you mean by remote service? and post some code or your error log

Comment: When defining the service in the Android Manifest, you specify it to be remote.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, what I did was using a Runnable inside a Service, and using a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecution`, as the following way:

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor execUpdateData = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
scheduledUpdateData = execUpdateData.scheduleAtFixedRate(new updateDataTask(), 0, sampling_storage_ms, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: Please give brief details on same so, other will understand what is scheduledUpdateData and new updateDataTask() etc.